# How to get exact count of used range of rows in excel using Epplus?

Tags: c#, epplus

I am trying to get a total number of rows being used in excel using Epplus but I am unable to get an exact count and the count also includes null I need an only exact range of used cells.

these lines of code I am using

```
FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage(fileinfo);
ExcelWorksheet w = p.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
int Rmax = w.Dimension.End.Row;
int Cmax = w.Dimension.End.Column;
Console.WriteLine(Rmax);
Console.WriteLine(Cmax);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get rows and columns from these lines

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
{
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
    int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;
}
```

Comment: hello brother, thanks for ur reply. I was having 39 rows and 33 columns but after deleting 5 rows my total count is reflecting as 39 only but the actual value must be 34.

Comment: How did you delete the row in excel.  Right Click on row in extreme left + Clear contents ?

Comment: I mean in your excel, Right click + Clear contents. This will delete only the contents not the row. Please check with Right Click + Delete. This will delete the entire row along with contents.

Comment: I have created an application which is used by the client, he will insert excel into the application and then values are read from that. so I don't have any idea how he is deleting the contents within that file.

Comment: If so, you have at-least one column in that excel file is mandatory. I mean for at-least one column mus have values. Based on that, you proceed further.

Comment: If you need only the exact range of used cells, try this string usedRange = worksheet.Dimension.Address;

Comment: Kindly note that if your client add empty rows, then those rows are also considerable.

Answer (score 2):

```
   int count = Rmax * Cmax;
   int firstCellValue = 0;
   int lastCellValue = 0;

   for (int row = 1; row <= Rmax; row++) {
    for (int column = 1; column <= Cmax; column++) {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheet.Cells[row, column].GetValue<String>())) {
      count--;
     }
    }
   }
```

**UPDATE**

```
     int rowCount = Rmax;
     int count = Rmax * Cmax;
     string firstCellValue = string.Empty;
     string lastCellValue = string.Empty;

     for (int row = 1; row <= Rmax; row++) {
      bool foundValue = false;
      int leftIndex = 1;
      int rightIndex = Cmax;

      for (int column = 1; column <= Cmax; column++) {
       if (leftIndex == rightIndex) {
        if (!foundValue) {
         rowCount--;
         break;
        }
       }
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheet.Cells[row, column].GetValue < String > ())) {
        foundValue = true;
        firstCellValue = worksheet.Cells[row, column].ToString();
        leftIndex++;
       }
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheet.Cells[row, rightIndex].GetValue < String > ())) {
        foundValue = true;
        lastCellValue = worksheet.Cells[row, rightIndex].ToString();
        rightIndex--;
       }

      }


     }

     Console.WriteLine("firstCellValue" + firstCellValue);
     Console.WriteLine("lastCellValue" + lastCellValue);
     Console.WriteLine("Number of cells" + rowCount);
```

Comment: Hi, brother, the solution u have shared is quite helpful but this will also remove any blank spaces between the rows. I just want the count of rows from start to end if there are few blanks in middle or start doesn't matter I just need the count from start to end that is last cell value.

Comment: Hi Abdul, If I understand your query correctly,  just traverse each row and maintain 2 pointers. one from
begin and the other one from end

The moment you find empty from the end that will your last cell value similarly with start

if they both become same  and no value was found decrease the count of row

Comment: Hi Shad, I have described my code in the question segment please try to help me as I am new to .Net Development.